# Find the minimum value of $\alpha$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $S$ be the set of all real numbers $\alpha$ such that the solution $y$ of the initial value problem

$\frac{dy}{dx}=y(2-y)$

$y(0) = \alpha$.

exists on $[0, ∞)$. Then the minimum of the set $S$ is equal to__

Using variable separable method ,

$\frac{dy}{y(2-y)}=dx$

$\ln|\frac{y}{y-2}|=2x+c$

Using the given condition i got

$y=\frac{(\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha-2})e^{2x}}{(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-2})e^{2x}-1}$

Now here since we want minimum then let $\alpha=0$ then our solution exist and $y(x)=0$ so $\alpha$ can't be greater than $0$ now we only need to check if $\alpha <0$ or not?
If $\alpha$ is negative then we don't need to worry about the numerator part thus our solution doesn't exist whenever
$(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-2})e^{2x}-1 =0$

Now , $e^{2x}=(\frac{\alpha-2}{\alpha})$

$e^{2x}=(1-\frac{2}{\alpha})$

Now how do i check further .
What should be the minimum value of $\alpha$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the solution as
$$y(x)=\frac{2ae^{2x}}{a(e^{2x}-1)+2}$$
Now we see that if $a\ne0$ there is a singularity iff $a(e^{2x}-1)+2=0$ or $x=\ln(1-2/a)/2$. This is nonnegative – and thus the putative $x$ is *not* in $S$ – *iff* $\ln(1-2/a)\ge0$ or $2/a\le0$ or $a\le0$.

When $a=0$ we just get $y=0$, which clearly exists on $[0,\infty)$, so $\min S=0$.